# How do I logout from vbscript?

Tags: windows, vbscript, logoff

I'm using a VBScript to run an application on my Win Server 2003, and I want it to log the user off after a set amount of time.  Something along the lines of:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set OExe = WshShell.exec("somecommand.exe")
WScript.Sleep 1000000
OExe.Terminate
<Insert LogOff code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
WshShell.Run "C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe /l", 0, false
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

```
Wscript.Sleep(100000)  
SET wshell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")  
wshell.exec("shutdown.exe -L -F")
```

Just tested  this on a w7 box, seems to work alright.

Answer (score 0):

Example using WMI:

```
Set oSystems = GetObject("winmgmts:{(Shutdown)}//./root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Primary=true")
For Each oSystem in oSystems
   'LOGOFF   = 0
   'SHUTDOWN = 1
   'REBOOT   = 2
   'FORCE    = 4
   'POWEROFF = 8
   oSystem.Win32Shutdown 0
Next
```